# How to overlap items using css Grid?

Tags: html, css, grid

I design an app using angular and There is a requirement that  I have to design the grid-like the below image. **item 2** is overlapped with **item1** and all items except item1 will span the width of the host element(container) element?

[image]

```
            <div class="item1">
               this is item 1           
            </div>
            <div class="item2">
               this is item 2           
            </div>
            <div class="item3">
               this is item 3           
            </div>
            <div class="item4">
               this is item 4           
            </div>
```

Can you help with my grid CSS?

```
  :host{
          height: 100vh;
          display: grid;          
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `.item1` and `.item2` on the same row and column (I've used `grid-area`), and then center `.item2` with `align-self`, and `justify-self`:

```css
.host {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
}

.item1, .item2 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1;
}

.item1 {
  background: red;
}

.item2 {
  background: purple;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  padding: 1em;
}

.item3 {
  background: blue;
}

.item4 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="host">
  <div class="item1">
    this is item 1
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
    this is item 2
  </div>
  <div class="item3">
    this is item 3
  </div>
  <div class="item4">
    this is item 4
  </div>
</div>
```